# Rails, Clearance, using User ID after logging in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I'm using clearance (https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/wiki) for authentication in my rails app. But I'm trying to figure out how to grab the user's ID in a view after logging in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/104e05d09de521f89dbef3191c749982221565a8/lib/clearance/authentication.rb#L7), looks like

```
current_user.id
```

should do the trick.

Comment: unfortunately the link is broken: redirects too many times

Comment: Updated the link to refer to the relevant code directly.